# Cosa significa "aere" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Rinascimento privato* di Maria Bellonci ho letto:

> C'eravamo isolate a Porto Mantovano nella mia preferita villa sul lago: preferita, perché pure vicinissima alla città, appena di là dal ponte San Giorgio, mi pareva per il suo rustico e gentile disegno,  per i boschetti deliziosi e il lago dalle correnti ventilate in buona posizione di **aere**, assai più grata delle sale di castello.

Non capisco il significato di "aere" in questo brano. Ho cercato il termine "aera", ma non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Qualcuno di voi ne sa qualcosa?

Comment: Come osservato da DaG, in questa accezione è stato soppiantato da *aria* ma sopravvive in termini come *aeriforme*, *aereo*, *aeroporto*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La parola è proprio “[aere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/aere)”, che è un sostantivo (singolare) ora antiquato, imparentato con “aria” e direttamente derivato dal latino *aer*. Si usa sia per riferirsi, come qui, all'aria (“A noi venendo per l’aere maligno”, Dante) che all'aspetto o all'indole di una persona.

Comment: Non avevo pensato a cercare proprio "aere" invece di "aera" nel dizionario!